# Why is the list not updating with the new data?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular and the data is coming back from my api call. The problem is my list is not populating with the updated data.

first partial:

```
 <div ng-controller="CustomerController" data-ng-init="init()" class="col-md-2">
    <select ng-model="customerKey" ng-options="customer.Key as customer.Value for customer in customers"></select>
</div>
```

second partial:

```
<div ng-controller="CustomerController">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5" style="outline: 1px solid black; margin-top: 1%">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="radio-inline" ng-repeat="customerOption in customerOptions">
                <input type="radio" id="{{customerOption.Value}}" name="customer" ng-change="getCustomers(customerType)" ng-model="customerType" ng-value="customerOption.Key" ng-checked="customerOption.Checked" />{{customerOption.Value}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var customer = angular.module('customer', []);

customer.controller('CustomerController', [
    "$scope", "customerService",
    function($scope, customerService) {
        $scope.customerOptions = CustomerOptions;

        $scope.getCustomers = function(customerType) {
            $scope.showContent = false;
            customerService.get(customerType).then(function (data) {
                $scope.customers = data;
            });
        };

        $scope.init = function() {
            $scope.getCustomers("1");
        }
    }
]);
```

service:

```
app.service('customerService', [
"$http", function ($http) {
    this.get = function(customerType) {
        var customers;
        if (customerType == "1") {
            getProduction().then(function(result) { customers = result.data; });
        } else if (customerType == "2") {
            getTest().then(function(result) { customers = result.data; });
        } else {
            getAll().then(function(result) { customers = result.data; });
        }
        return customers;
    };

    var getTest = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/Customer/GetTest",
        })
         .success(function (data) {
             return data;
         });
    };

    var getProduction = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/Customer/GetProduction",
        })
         .success(function (data) {
             return data;
         });
    };

    var getAll = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/Customer/GetAll",
        })
         .success(function (data) {
             return data;
         });
    };
    }
]);
```

If you click on any of the radio buttons, they return the appropriate list to the service function; however, I cannot get the select list to populate with the new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here in your `get` function:

```
this.get = function(customerType) {
        var customers;
        if (customerType == "1") {
            getProduction().then(function(result) { customers = result.data; });
        } else if (customerType == "2") {
            getTest().then(function(result) { customers = result.data; });
        } else {
            getAll().then(function(result) { customers = result.data; });
        }
        return customers;
    };
```

You are defining the `customers` var, and then you send out an asynchronous request and returning the still undefined customers, since `getProduction()/getTest()/getAll()` are all asynchronous.

You should have your `get` function return a promise, and resolve the inner async functions based on success/error:

```
this.get = function(customerType) {

        var deferred = this.$q.defer();

        var customers;
        if (customerType == "1") {
            getProduction().success(function(result) { return deferred.resolve(result); })
                           .error(function(e) { return deferred.reject(e); });
        } else if (customerType == "2") {
            getTest().success(function(result) { return deferred.resolve(result); })
                     .error(function(e) { return deferred.reject(e); });
        } else {
            getAll().success(function(result) { return deferred.resolve(result); })
                    .error(function(e) { return deferred.reject(e); });
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

Finally, since I added the `.success/.error` in the `get` function, you can remove it from each of the `get***()` functions so they'll look like this:

```
var getAll = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/Customer/GetAll",
        });
    };
```

Comment: Is there some secret to using the lambda statements in angular / js, When I try and use them, I get errors (expected; or ))

Comment: @Robert No secret that I know of :) You can substitute them. `result => deferred.resolve(result)` == `function(result) { return deferred.resolve(result); }`

Comment: @Robert Perhaps it's my typescript that can interpret it... I'll edit the answer with the normal syntax.

Comment: what is $q and does it need to be injected?

Comment: @Robert Yes, it needs to be injected. Read here about it: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: @Robert But it does after the ajax call ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69136/discussion-between-robert-and-omri-aharon).

Comment: Okay I need some guidance on where to look for how to accomplish this.

Comment: @Robert All you need to do is: (1) create a service that has a variable `customers`. (2) inject that service to the controller. (3) instead of updating `$scope.customers = data`, update `service.customers = data`. (4) in the view, instead of writing `customers`, write `getCustomers()` and have a function in the controller `$scope.getCustomers = function () { return service.customers; }`